# Vert.x. How to enable automatic redeploy in a project with multiple modules?

Tags: gradle, vert.x, vertx-verticle

How can we enable auto redeploy for multiple modules when using `Vert.x`?

For example, if we have a structure like this one:

```
build.gradle
settings.gradle
main
    build.gradle
    src/main/java/MainVerticle.java
    src/main/java/JavaVerticle.java
kotlin
    build.gradle
    src/main/java/KotlinVerticle.kt
```

where the `main` module is written in Java and the `kotlin` module is written in Kotlin.

Our `settings.gradle` can have something like:

```
include(":main")
include(":kotlin")
```

The `main/build.gradle` can have something like:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation project(":kotlin")
}

...

def mainVerticleName = "MainVerticle"
def watchForChange = "src/**/*"
def doOnChange = "./../gradlew classes"

run {
  args = ["run", mainVerticleName, "--redeploy=$watchForChange", "--launcher-class=$mainClassName", "--on-redeploy=$doOnChange"]
}
```

How could we propertly configure our project so when we change some file inside the `main` or the `kotlin` module the verticles are redeployed?

Answer (score 1):

You should modify `watchForChange` (beware relative paths) to watch for changes.

Something like `["src/**/*", "../kotlin/**/*"]`, etc.